# how to manage list string to make condition

Tags: list, flutter

Hello I tried to make an action if I have _accelerometerValuesx > value 
but when I use symbole like  >  but I have this issue : the operator ">" isn't define is the class list

example:

```
if ( _accelerometerValuesx >= 2.0){
      //action
    }
```

my code :

```
  List<double> _accelerometerValuesx;
  List<StreamSubscription<dynamic>> _streamSubscriptions =
  <StreamSubscription<dynamic>>[];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> accelerometerx =
    _accelerometerValuesx?.map((double v) => v.toStringAsFixed(1))?.toList();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sensor Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Accelerometerx: $accelerometerx'),
              ],
            ),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
        _streamSubscriptions
        .add(accelerometerEvents.listen((AccelerometerEvent event) {
      setState(() {
        _accelerometerValuesx = <double>[event.x];
      });
    }));
  }
```

Comment: If you get an error message please add the full and exact error message to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pick a specific element from the list

```
if ( _accelerometerValuesx[0] >= 2.0){
  //action
}
```

where `_accelerometerValuesx[0]` reads the first entry of the `_accelerometerValuesx` list and compares that with `2.0`